# python: sys.argv[0] meaning in official documentation

Tags: python, argv, sys

Quoting from [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html):

"`sys.argv` The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the `-c` command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to the string `'-c'`. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, `argv[0]` is the empty string."

Am I missing something, or `sys.argv[0]` always returns the script name, and to get `'-c'` I'd have to use `sys.argv[1]`?

I'm testing with Python 3.2 on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Eheh I stupidly misinterpreted `-c` as just an example option, instead of a real option for `python`, nevermind...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, if you invoke Python with `-c` to run commands from the command line, your `sys.argv[0]` will be `-c`:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe -c "import sys; print sys.argv[0]"
-c
```

Answer (score 8):

When Python is invoked as `python script.py` then `sys.argv[0] == 'script.py'`. When you invoke `python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv'` then `sys.argv[0] == '-c'` indicating the script body was passed as a string on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

`python -c` executes a command passed on the command line, rather than a script from a file.  `sys.argv[0]` will be set to `"-c"`.

If you run a *script* with a `-c` flag, then yes, `sys.argv[1]` will be set to `"-c"` and `sys.argv[0]` will be set to the name of the script.

Comment: I just thought of `-c` as an example, like in `script -c`, and didn't think of it as the real python option... ^^'