# Python keeps telling me that I'm passing in more than one argument, when I'm not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python Version: 3.11.4

I'm using a VENV called `FontTools` with all my dependencies installed.

Script:

```
import os.path
import sys
from fontTools import ttLib
from fontmeta import FontMeta

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print("Usage: Only one argument required: [FONT]")
    exit(1)

fontfile = sys.argv[1]
meta_instance = FontMeta(fontfile)
metadata = meta_instance.get_full_data()

print(metadata)
```

Usage:
`D:\Dev\Python\Font Scripts> python getFontMeta.py "SharpSans-Bold.otf"`

Returns:
`Usage: Only one argument required: [FONT]`

I inspected `sys.argv[0]`, and it's set to the name of my script: `getFontMeta.py`
`sys.argv[1]` is set to the font I passed in.

Why is this happening? This script worked before, is this new behavior in Python v3.11.4?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The filename is the first argument. It's always been this way. So you expect exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: Ok, weird. I could have sworn this script was working before as-is. I didn't know Python behaved that way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, your script probably worked if you didn't have the length check, because you correctly access the fontfile at index 1, with index 0 being the filename. Here is a SO question that asks the same for Python 3.2 indicating its been there for long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222408/python-sys-argv0-meaning-in-official-documentation

Comment: Just for the record, this behavior was taken from the C language, going back more than 50 years.  C programs take two parameters `(argc, argv)`, where `argc` is the count of elements,  `argv[0]` is always the program name.  This is not new behavior.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the history lesson! Good information to know.